# ¿Cuál es el alcance de la declaración strict_types en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy usando [**strict_types**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-does-strict-types-do-in-php) en un proyecto con PHP 7.2. Al inicio del fichero principal tengo:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace ironwoods\myproject;
```

A continuación se hacen algunos imports.

Quisiera saber si **¿la declaración de *strict_types* debe ir en cada fichero del proyecto o afecta también a aquellos ficheros que son importados por aquel en que se declara?**

Comment: el uso de `strict_types` solo afecta a la lógica que esta declarada dentro del archivo que la contiene, para los archivos que invoquen a aquel dodne esta instrucción esté contenida, no les aplica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El alcance de la sentencia `strict_types` solo trabaja de manera directa en aquel archivo que lo contiene, en aquellos bloques de código que estan directamente debajo de dicha directiva.

Referencia de la documentación (declare strict)[http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict]

Ejemplo

```
app.php

<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

$num1;
$num2;
function sumar(int $num1, int $num2){
    return $num1 + $num2;
}


echo sumar(10.0, 10);
```

Dará como error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to sumar()
>   must be of the type int, float given......

Sin embargo si en un archivo `app2.php` hago un require de ese mismo archivo `app.php` para usar la misma función suma()

```
<?php 

require 'app.php';

echo sumar(20.0, "60");
```

Y después ejecuto el archivo desde la consola, obtengo lo siguiente

```
$ php app2.php
80
```